# Wordpress & Elementor Custom module register_controls

Tags: wordpress, module, elementor

register_controls is the function we created to add control in the Elementor to set some values.

But while registering we need the value of one dropdown to get the values of another dropdown. When we are using this code it breaks the entire system we built but while we comment it is working absolutely fine.

Here is the code:

```
Inside this register_controls() 
// CATEGORY CHOOSE - example - start
$this->start_controls_section(
    'category_section',
    [
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Choose a Category', 'elementor-list-widget' ),
        'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
    ]
);

$this->add_control(
    'cat_id',
    [
        'label' => __( 'Choose a Category', 'plugin-domain' ),
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
        'options' => $optionCat,
        // 'multiple' => true,
        'default' => []
    ]
);

$this->end_controls_section();

$default_value = $this->get_settings( 'cat_id' );

// CATEGORY CHOOSE - example - end
```